# Complex Analysis: using $z = x + iy$ make $f(z)$ in terms of $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

So for the function $f: D \subset C \to C$

$$f(z) = y^3 - 3x^2y + i(y^2 - 3xy^2 + x^3 - x^2 + B)$$
$z = x + iy$

$(x, y) \in R^2$

$B \in R$

How do I make $f(z)$ in terms of $z$. I would put up what I got up to trying to do this, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard way is to replace $x,y$ in the given expression for $f$ using the identities
\begin{align*}
x&=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}\\[4pt]
y&=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}\\
\end{align*}
and then expand and simplify.

The result will be an expression in terms of $z$ and $\bar{z}$.

Comment: $x = z, y = 0$? i guess the bars are missing

Comment: @pointguard0: I don't follow.

Comment: Another, somewhat more direct, way is to compute $z^2$ and $z^3$ in terms of $(x,y)$ and... to rejoice.

Comment: @quasi, it was written: $x = \frac{z + z}{2}$ and $y = \frac{z - z}{2i}$.

Comment: @pointguard0: Ok, I see your edit, thanks, but actually, there _were_ bars, via the mathjax format $\bar{z}$ (backslash bar{z}).

Comment: @quasi, yep, there indeed were bars, but for some reason they weren’t displayed (at least for me).